# How to enforce client code to use the APIs as expected/published

Tags: java, performance, api, loops, design-patterns

I wanted to develop an API which will be consumed by third party - where we don't have much control over how third party will use the API. Communicating the correct way to use the API via public documentation doesn't guarantee the correct API usage.

**Is there any technique or design pattern to force the API consumers to use the API method as expected?**

Here are two usage examples of an API which has a method to tweet the statuses:

- **Usage #1** consumer can tweet multiple statuses in a single call by passing an array of string to the method. This is the intended use by API designer.
- **Usage #2** consumer still tweet multiple statuses but one status at a time, ending up calling tweet method ten times. That is not the intended use and can cause performance issue.

I am looking a solution to enforce/prevent this API usage.

API Packaged/Delivered as a jar:

```
package com.api;

public class API {
    public API() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void tweet(String [] statuses) {
        // TODO - very expensive db call to store statuses

        // open db connection
        // insert/update
        // close db connection
    }
}
```

Client calling API:

```
package com;

import com.api.API;

public class Example {
    public Example() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private static void client() {
        API api = new API();

        // API Usage #1 - WAS Expected
        String [] statuses1 = new String[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            statuses1[i] = new String("[" + i + "] - statuses1");
        }
        // one call to process all 10 statuses -- RIGHT
        api.tweet(statuses1);

        // API Usage #2 - NOT Recommended
        String [] statuses2 = new String[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            statuses2[i] = new String("[" + i + "] - statuses2");

            // ten calls to process all 10 statuses -- WRONG
            api.tweet(statuses2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If calling the `tweet` method multiple times in a short period isn't expected usage, you will need to check for rate limits on the server side. Many APIs do this, limiting clients to a specific number of calls in a certain time period. You could also build logic to handle multiple `tweet` calls from a single client and construct a single call yourself.

Comment: @admdrew Thanks -- what if the Api code is a jar delivered to the client to add in the classpath. There is no server side for the sake of the simplicity.

Comment: I am looking to find a way to detect the callerId and keep a call count with duration if same cid but not sure if this is the right way - Thread.currentThread().getId();
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3];

Comment: While You can and should validate data and enforce data consistency , validating client behavior and enforcing rules there is a bit tricky. Because you don't want to diminish client's capabilities and wrongly block good clients. Still as far as overwhelming requests are concerned you can implement strategies like "exponential backoff" etc to limit clients abusing server bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should trust your clients a bit that they do the right thing. But maybe you can do the batching instead of them:

Collect the requests in `API.tweet` yourself. Maybe you can aggregate requests from different clients. Maybe you can aggregate requests from a single client over some longer time period.

This should solve it. If not, here are more ideas:

Probably you can easily find out that a client call your method multiple times in a row and throw an exception to teach them the hard way. But I'd find it better to special handle such client, e.g., by aggregating their calls (while calls from the more conforming clients get passed immediately).

---

You wrote

```
    // open db connection
    // insert/update
    // close db connection
```

and that's usually wrong. Closing the connection means losing a lot of time, connection pooling is the standard solution.

Comment: based on your idea putting all the requests in a queue and process the queue periodically will do.